# Заменить значения в тэгах по шаблону (DOM, JS)

Tags: javascript, dom

Допустим есть элементы

```
<li class="list-item green" data-test-id="1">green</li>
```

Необходимо обновить текст по шаблону, чтобы стало

```
<li class="list-item green" data-test-id="1">1 green</li>
```

Понимаю, что надо начать с Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li')), а дальше труба.

Comment: какой шаблон-то?

Comment: @Grundy  ${data-test-id} ${text} - атрибут data-test-id к тексту в li

Answer (score 0):

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        let lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); // Получаем все элементы с тегом li

        for(let i=0;i<lis.length;i++){ // Преебираем их
            let style = lis[i].className.split(' '); // Получаем название класса и разбиваем по пробелму
            let id = lis[i].dataset.testId; // Получаем id из data аттрибута
            lis[i].innerText = id+' '+style[1]; // Добавляем в текст id и название цвета класса.
        }
    }
```

```css
    .green{
        color: green;
    }
    .red{
        color: red;
    }
    .blue{
        color: blue;
    }
    .yellow{
        color: yellow;
    }
    .black{
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="list-item green" data-test-id="1"></li>
    <li class="list-item red" data-test-id="2"></li>
    <li class="list-item blue" data-test-id="3"></li>
    <li class="list-item yellow" data-test-id="4"></li>
    <li class="list-item black" data-test-id="5"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: очень крутой код. можно как-нибудь попроще с reduce или map? допустим получил я все li со страницы. теперь мне нужно опять их вывести, но с измененным значением в теге - не просто цвет, а с номерком *чешет репу*

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, так:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'))
  .forEach((li) => { li.textContent = `${li.dataset.testId} ${li.textContent}`; });
```

```html
<li class="list-item green" data-test-id="1">green</li> 
<li class="list-item green" data-test-id="2">green</li>
```